# blackberry signing application

Tags: blackberry

is it required to sign the blackberry application before installing it to the device ? , only for testing purpose while developing not for market release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are installing it on to a physical device AND you use the protected APIS (which is pretty much any not J2me only classes) **you do need to sign the applications.**

Yes even for development.

Getting a [signing key practically free](https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/) and the process is very simple and you don't need to go through an approval process. I would HIGHLY recommend you get a signing cert even if your application currently doesn't need one (but since you are asking I assume it does)

Comment: Nice answer durbin, but I would like to draw your attention to one point which is rather a correction, getting signing key is almost free, AFAIK they will cost you a minimal amount (1$ ?) which is refundable after verification. For cross check visit this link https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/

Comment: Thanks Pransham I updated my answer, I ordered keys like last month and it was $20.00 so they dropped the price again awesome

Comment: I also ordered two keys, one for my laptop and other for my workstation, spent $40 a week before they made free.